# Change Spotify song while on the background

Tags: spotify

Sometimes I'm playing a game while listening to music, or my phone is just locked with Go Locker, and there is no hardkey/softkey to change song except by going to the application or widget, which takes some seconds and putting other apps to sleep.

Is there any way to set up long press of volume keys to this?

Comment: What Android version/ROM are you on?

Comment: Cyanogenmod allows this, like many other custom roms but only if the display is off.

Comment: Galaxy S3, 4.1.4, Vodafone's ROM.